# Cytoscape.js not setting compound node properties when exported as json

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am currently trying to export my Cytoscape.js graph as json to later import it into the Cytoscape application. For some nodes I need to add a compound node after the layout process, so they are not included in the layout process and do not affect the node positions.

After the layout I add the parent nodes via cy.add() and the child nodes are added to the parent nodes via ele.move().

When I debug the nodes the properties autoHeight and autoWidth are set but when I read them it results in undefinded and the positions are not set according to their child nodes.

```
var json = cy.json();
var jsonNodes = json.elements.nodes;
var graphNodes = cy.nodes(':parent');

jsonNodes.forEach(jsonNode => {
          graphNodes.forEach(graphNode => {
                        if (jsonNode.data['id'] == graphNode._private.data['id']){
                            if(graphNode._private['autoHeight'] != undefined) {
                                let height = graphNode._private['autoHeight'];
                                let width = graphNode._private['autoWidth'];
                                jsonNode.data['height'] = height;
                                jsonNode.data['width'] = width;
                                jsonNode.data['opacity'] = 70;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                )
            });
```

I want the json to include the parents width, height and position (according to the position of their child node).